# How do I remap/filter a nested array's elements by comparing element attributes that represent hierarchy/relationship to one another?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I **think** this may be somewhat similar to this question [How to use graph lookup aggregation in a embedded array document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47884945/how-to-use-graph-lookup-aggregation-in-a-embedded-array-document/55738732#55738732) but there was never an answer and I don't have the reputation to make a comment to see if the author ever found a solution.

While the collection will have thousands of docs, I will only be concered with 1 of them when querying. Current intent is to use an initial `$match` stage that will result in a single doc.

**Sample document**

```
{
  attrA: 'foo',
  attrB: 'bar',
  versions: [
    {
      status: "live",
      things: [
        {
          key: "thing_1",
          parent: null
          slug: "thing-1-slug"
        },
        {
          key: "thing_2",
          parent: "thing-1-slug",
          slug: "thing-2-slug"
        },
        {
          key: "thing_3",
          parent: "thing-2-slug",
          slug: "thing-3-slug"
        },
        {
          key: "thing_4",
          parent: null,
          slug: "thing-4-slug"
        },
        {
          key: "thing_5",
          parent: "thing-2-slug",
          slug: "thing-5-slug"
        },
        {
          key: "thing_6",
          parent: "thing-4-slug",
          slug: "thing-6-slug"
        },
        {
          key: "thing_7",
          parent: null,
          slug: "thing-7-slug"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      status: "draft"
      things: [] // same structure and content of things above
    }
  ]
}
```

**Notes**:

- I've tried various aggregation queries but haven't had much luck at all. Happy to post some of them if it would be helpful but none of them were close to the desired outcome.
- I only care about a single document in the collection at query-time (intent is to `$match` as first stage)
- I have no control over the original attributes or document structure at this time.
- I would really like to do this **without** having to use things like `$project` because I won't know all the original document's attributes in advance (`attrA` and `attrB` in example). My thinking is this might be possible via operators like `$addField` but I'm not 100% sure what all the stages might look like.
- I only care about the `versions` array element that has `status === "live"`. If there's a way to overwrite `versions` to only have the "live" element in it in the query results, even better.
- The `key` attribute of a particular "things" element will be a known value (based on a HTTP request payload) and should/could serve as "starting point" for the relationship/hierarchy stuff.
- The `parent` attribute of each things element either points to another thing array element's `slug` attribute or is `null`
- Multiple `things` elements could have the same `parent`
- There is no limit to the potential depth

**Desired Outcome**:

Knowing that I want to "start" at a `thing` with, for example, `key === "thing_3"`, how can I create a query that will remap/filter `things` to be an array of "thing elements" that:

- includes all elements of the `things` array that represent the hierarchy/relationship starting with the item where `key === "thing_3"`
- (bonus) limit the `versions` array to a single element that has `status === "live"` and has its `things` array rewritten based on #1

**Example of desired query results**:

- note the absence of `things` elements with `key` of thing_4, thing_6, and thing_7 since they had no parent/relation to `things` elements starting at `key === "thing_3"`
- if it simplifies things, the element with `key === "thing_5"` (also has `parent === "thing-2-slug"`) can be included in the results but ideally would not.

```
{
  attrA: 'foo',
  attrB: 'bar',
  versions: [
    {
      things: [
        {
          key: "thing_1",
          parent: null
          slug: "thing-1-slug"
        },
        {
          key: "thing_2",
          parent: "thing-1-slug",
          slug: "thing-2-slug"
        },
        {
          key: "thing_3",
          parent: "thing-2-slug",
          slug: "thing-3-slug"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After adding so many stages I found the results although it's not appropriate format so you can customize or you can optimize as well:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$versions"
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id:1,
            attrA:1,
            attrB:1,
            versions: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$versions.things",
                    as: "th",
                    cond:  { 
                        $or: [
                            { $ne: [ "$$th.parent", null ]  },
                            { 
                                $and: [
                                    { $eq: [ "$$th.parent", null ]  },
                                    { $eq: [ "$$th.key", "thing_1" ] }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$versions"
    },


    {
        $graphLookup: {
            from: "slug",
            startWith: "$versions.slug",
            connectFromField: "versions.slug",
            connectToField: "versions.things.parent",
            as: "reportingHierarchy"
        }
    },
    {
        $match: { 
            $expr:  { $ne: [ {$size: "$reportingHierarchy" },0 ] }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            parents: { $addToSet: "$versions.slug"  },
            data: { $push: "$$ROOT"}
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$data"
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            newVersions:
            {
                $map:
                {
                    input: "$data.reportingHierarchy",
                    as: "hierarchy",
                    in: {
                        "columns": {
                            $map:
                            {
                                input: "$$hierarchy.versions",
                                as: "version",
                                in: {
                                    "$filter": {
                                        "input": "$$version.things", 
                                        "as": "th", 
                                        "cond": { 
                                            $or: [
                                                { $setIsSubset: [ ["$$th.parent"], "$parents" ]  },
                                                { $eq: [ "$$th.key", 'thing_1']}
                                            ]
                                        } 
                                    } 
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
    },

    {
        $project: {
            newVersions:1
        }
    }

])
```

The resulted response of this query is as below:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : null,
    "newVersions" : [
        {
            "columns" : [
                [
                    {
                        "key" : "thing_1",
                        "parent" : null,
                        "slug" : "thing-1-slug"
                    },
                    {
                        "key" : "thing_2",
                        "parent" : "thing-1-slug",
                        "slug" : "thing-2-slug"
                    },
                    {
                        "key" : "thing_3",
                        "parent" : "thing-2-slug",
                        "slug" : "thing-3-slug"
                    },
                    {
                        "key" : "thing_5",
                        "parent" : "thing-2-slug",
                        "slug" : "thing-5-slug"
                    }
                ],
                [
                    {
                        "key" : "thing_1",
                        "parent" : null,
                        "slug" : "thing-1-slug"
                    },
                    {
                        "key" : "thing_2",
                        "parent" : "thing-1-slug",
                        "slug" : "thing-2-slug"
                    },
                    {
                        "key" : "thing_3",
                        "parent" : "thing-2-slug",
                        "slug" : "thing-3-slug"
                    },
                    {
                        "key" : "thing_5",
                        "parent" : "thing-2-slug",
                        "slug" : "thing-5-slug"
                    }
                ]
            ]
        }
    ]
},

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : null,
    "newVersions" : [
        {
            "columns" : [
                [
                    {
                        "key" : "thing_1",
                        "parent" : null,
                        "slug" : "thing-1-slug"
                    },
                    {
                        "key" : "thing_2",
                        "parent" : "thing-1-slug",
                        "slug" : "thing-2-slug"
                    },
                    {
                        "key" : "thing_3",
                        "parent" : "thing-2-slug",
                        "slug" : "thing-3-slug"
                    },
                    {
                        "key" : "thing_5",
                        "parent" : "thing-2-slug",
                        "slug" : "thing-5-slug"
                    }
                ],
                [
                    {
                        "key" : "thing_1",
                        "parent" : null,
                        "slug" : "thing-1-slug"
                    },
                    {
                        "key" : "thing_2",
                        "parent" : "thing-1-slug",
                        "slug" : "thing-2-slug"
                    },
                    {
                        "key" : "thing_3",
                        "parent" : "thing-2-slug",
                        "slug" : "thing-3-slug"
                    },
                    {
                        "key" : "thing_5",
                        "parent" : "thing-2-slug",
                        "slug" : "thing-5-slug"
                    }
                ]
            ]
        }
    ]
},

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : null,
    "newVersions" : [
        {
            "columns" : [
                [
                    {
                        "key" : "thing_1",
                        "parent" : null,
                        "slug" : "thing-1-slug"
                    },
                    {
                        "key" : "thing_2",
                        "parent" : "thing-1-slug",
                        "slug" : "thing-2-slug"
                    },
                    {
                        "key" : "thing_3",
                        "parent" : "thing-2-slug",
                        "slug" : "thing-3-slug"
                    },
                    {
                        "key" : "thing_5",
                        "parent" : "thing-2-slug",
                        "slug" : "thing-5-slug"
                    }
                ],
                [
                    {
                        "key" : "thing_1",
                        "parent" : null,
                        "slug" : "thing-1-slug"
                    },
                    {
                        "key" : "thing_2",
                        "parent" : "thing-1-slug",
                        "slug" : "thing-2-slug"
                    },
                    {
                        "key" : "thing_3",
                        "parent" : "thing-2-slug",
                        "slug" : "thing-3-slug"
                    },
                    {
                        "key" : "thing_5",
                        "parent" : "thing-2-slug",
                        "slug" : "thing-5-slug"
                    }
                ]
            ]
        }
    ]
},

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : null,
    "newVersions" : [
        {
            "columns" : [
                [
                    {
                        "key" : "thing_1",
                        "parent" : null,
                        "slug" : "thing-1-slug"
                    },
                    {
                        "key" : "thing_2",
                        "parent" : "thing-1-slug",
                        "slug" : "thing-2-slug"
                    },
                    {
                        "key" : "thing_3",
                        "parent" : "thing-2-slug",
                        "slug" : "thing-3-slug"
                    },
                    {
                        "key" : "thing_5",
                        "parent" : "thing-2-slug",
                        "slug" : "thing-5-slug"
                    }
                ],
                [
                    {
                        "key" : "thing_1",
                        "parent" : null,
                        "slug" : "thing-1-slug"
                    },
                    {
                        "key" : "thing_2",
                        "parent" : "thing-1-slug",
                        "slug" : "thing-2-slug"
                    },
                    {
                        "key" : "thing_3",
                        "parent" : "thing-2-slug",
                        "slug" : "thing-3-slug"
                    },
                    {
                        "key" : "thing_5",
                        "parent" : "thing-2-slug",
                        "slug" : "thing-5-slug"
                    }
                ]
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The result is upwind so there are multiple entries but you can customize it.

**Note:** On the bases of the value of "thing_1" You will get the hierarchy data as per your requirement.

Comment: apologies for delay in responding here, I appreciate you taking the time to help with this!


Unfortunately, I'm getting zero (0) results when executing your query against the sample data provided.  What version of MongoDB did you use to produce these results? I've tried it in 3.4 (`$expr` not available) as well as 3.6 and 4.1.10. Was thinking that might be my issue but so far no luck.

Comment: Breaking down the stages, `$graphLookup` currently results in the `reportingHierarchy` arrays all being empty. I'm going to keep tinkering on my end but wanted to post update in case it was helpful to you.

Comment: Did you happen to introduce a secondary collection called `slug` to use as the `from` value for `$graphLookup`? That's the only thing I can think of as I cannot find documentation or examples of using `$graphLookup` without `from` being a collection (e.g., can't be a previous stage's results).

Comment: No, Actually Slug was dummy name of my collection. it is the same collection.

Comment: I took your document and created a collection on my local named as "slug" and then applied all stages on the same collection.

Comment: I need to spend more time to achieve your desired result but if you found the same then please post your query.

Comment: Sincerest apologies; I'm not sure what I did wrong the first 3 times but I started from scratch and your current progress is working for me as well now.

Comment: If it's of any use or makes things easier, I just found out I'm actually going to be querying from the opposite "end" of the relationship. Given the sample data, this would be starting with `key === "thing_3"`. I'm assuming queries from either "direction" would look very similar but wanted to mention it in case it's easier. Also happy to edit my question to reflect this if you'd prefer but didn't want to do so without discussing with you first.  I really appreciate all your help with this!

Comment: I'm unsure what the proper process is here but just wanted to let you know that I edited the question based on my previous comments as well as exploration of your current answer in hopes of adding clarity.